# Has anybody had any experience with getting Uploadify file uploader to work within an asp.net updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

I'm having problems getting [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) to work in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel. I'm not getting the "Browse" button displayed and so am unable to select any images for update.

It works perfectly outside of the UpdatePanel proving I have hooked everything up correctly.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I succesfully implemented uploadify in an dynamicdata updatepanel, can you add your code and the jquery that replaces the button, so i can have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

check the URLs are correctly formatted:

`/uploadify/Uploader.ashx`

try with

`uploadify/Uploader.ashx`,

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code the first thing that pops up in my mind is, is you ClientIDMode set to Static?